# How to set and check interruption status of Runnable added to ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading

I need a correct way how can I implement this using new approach such as `ExecutorService`. In the `Thread` we have `interrupt()`, in the `ExecutorService` there is `shutdown`. So, how can I signal all threads to stop? How can I determine that `Runnable` must stop itself?

```
public class OldStyle {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        task.start();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        task.interrupt();
    }

    static class MyTask extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                // ...do work...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose to do something like this, but there is no `isInterrupted()` :

```
class ModernWay {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(new MyTask());
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(1L, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }

    static class MyTask implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                // ...do work...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` should work.

Comment: Is this approach good enough to be used in production?

Comment: Yes, it's good enough. However I'm not sure how will any thread will call the  interrupt on the thread in the Executor Thread Pool. As No one has reference to the Executor threads.

Comment: Calling `shutdownNow()` will interrupt all threads in an Executor pool.